# Unable to clearInterval on this function

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I've been struggling to clear an Interval. It is inside a function that I call on a `forEach` statement for multiple objects.

The `clearInterval` is called inside a `catch()` for a promise. When it fails the `console.log()` works but not the clearInterval.

The code is as follows:

```
const myfunction = (object) => {
    console.log(`Starting Interval for ${object.name}...`)
    var timerLoop = setInterval( () => {
        console.log(`Interval for ${object.name}`)
        doSomething(object)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
            doTheThing(result)
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log('There was an error')
            clearInterval(timerLoop)
            console.error(err)
        })
    }, 1000)
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599878/can-clearinterval-be-called-inside-setinterval) question and it's answer, I should be able to call  `clearInterval()` from inside the actual interval, but I don't seem to get what is wrong with it.

What am I missing?

Comment: just for extra (or some) debugging, add `console.log(timerLoop)` inside both .then and .catch, just to see if things are as you expect them to be

Comment: Post a test case, use this as a base: https://jsfiddle.net/7csd89L1/

Comment: Assuming that `doSomething(object)` returns a Promise, your rejection function is executing. We can't see why.